# How apply and why this FontBase add two horizontal-Parallel to the text while using iText 5.5.2

Tags: android, fonts, itext, arabic

As i mentioned FontBase applied the proper font but also add two horizontal-Parallel line to the text as shown below:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    BaseFont bf_frs = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/Far_Talat.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
    LanguageProcessor lp = new ArabicLigaturizer();
    Font F_far = new Font(bf_frs, 18, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, BaseColor.BLACK);

    String para1 = "نمونه های بتن آزمایشگاهی اخذ شده در محل به قرار ذیل میباشد";
    Paragraph paragraph_part_1 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph_part_1.add(new Phrase(lp.process(para1), F_far));
    paragraph_part_1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(paragraph_part_1);
```

ttf file is standard and language is Farsi and very close to Arabic language.

So how omit these two lines.

Thanks..

Comment: iText doesn't add those lines, so they are probably part of the glyphs in the font. Can you share the file Far_Talat.ttf so that we can test for ourselves? I've never seen this kind of behavior.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/25dHl3ONba/far_dastnevis.html

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/XQsN4A6Ice/Far_Talat.html

Comment: oh...Sorry I'm not using 5.2.2 . I'm using 5.5.2 and I've edited question's title.

Comment: I don't use 4shared and I have no intention of using it as I don't trust the way it asked for social media logins to get a file.

Comment: oh sorry..But i think there is no need for you to test these font files cause the problem solved. Thank you so much. but if you you want please give me a way to send them for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Font.DEFAULTSIZE` to `Font.NORMAL`.

Also you shouldn't use `ArabicLigaturizer` directly. Try elements which have `RunDirection` such as `PdfPTable` and `PdfPCell`. These elements support `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL`.

Comment: problem solved, Thanks. I've just change DEFAULTSIZE to NORMAL as you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Font.**DEFAULTSIZE** to Font.**NORMAL** and You good to go.

Thanks "VahidN" for his recommendation.